# Keras multi gpu model tries to allocate model in non existant device CPU:1

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to train a model in keras. I have 4 gpus and 1 cpu. When I start training keras/tensorflow tries to use cpu 1 device which is non existant. I am running keras 2.1.6 and the latest tensorflow release was built from source.

```py
with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)

p_model = multi_gpu_model(model , 4)
p_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                       optimizer='rmsprop',
                       metrics=['accuracy'])

batch_size = 32
p_model.fit(x=train_x, 
            y=train_y, 
            batch_size=batch_size, 
            epochs=50, 
            verbose=1, 
            validation_data=(test_x, test_y), 
            shuffle=True)
```

I got the following error when I try to start training. I am not sure why it's trying to use cpu 1   even though its non existant.

```py
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1321     try:
-> 1322       return fn(*args)
   1323     except errors.OpError as e:

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run_fn(feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1306       return self._call_tf_sessionrun(
-> 1307           options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1308 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _call_tf_sessionrun(self, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1408           self._session, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1409           run_metadata)
   1410     else:

InvalidArgumentError: Creating a partition for /device:CPU:1 which doesn't exist in the list of available devices. Available devices: /device:CPU:0,/device:GPU:0,/device:GPU:1,/device:GPU:2,/device:GPU:3

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-ad177e58b8dc> in <module>()
     19                 verbose=1,
     20                 validation_data=(test_x, test_y),
---> 21                 shuffle=True)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
   1703                               initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
   1704                               steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
-> 1705                               validation_steps=validation_steps)
   1706 
   1707     def evaluate(self, x=None, y=None,

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in _fit_loop(self, f, ins, out_labels, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, val_f, val_ins, shuffle, callback_metrics, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps)
   1234                         ins_batch[i] = ins_batch[i].toarray()
   1235 
-> 1236                     outs = f(ins_batch)
   1237                     if not isinstance(outs, list):
   1238                         outs = [outs]

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in __call__(self, inputs)
   2480         session = get_session()
   2481         updated = session.run(fetches=fetches, feed_dict=feed_dict,
-> 2482                               **self.session_kwargs)
   2483         return updated[:len(self.outputs)]
   2484 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    898     try:
    899       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 900                          run_metadata_ptr)
    901       if run_metadata:
    902         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1133     if final_fetches or final_targets or (handle and feed_dict_tensor):
   1134       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
-> 1135                              feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
   1136     else:
   1137       results = []

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1314     if handle is None:
   1315       return self._do_call(_run_fn, feeds, fetches, targets, options,
-> 1316                            run_metadata)
   1317     else:
   1318       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, handle, feeds, fetches)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1333         except KeyError:
   1334           pass
-> 1335       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1336 
   1337   def _extend_graph(self):

InvalidArgumentError: Creating a partition for /device:CPU:1 which doesn't exist in the list of available devices. Available devices: /device:CPU:0,/device:GPU:0,/device:GPU:1,/device:GPU:2,/device:GPU:3
```

Comment: What if you remove your tf.device line?

Comment: Tried it, got the same error.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with my backend(tensorflow) installation.

Comment: Could you describe what the issue was and how you resolved it? Otherwise the answer is hardly useful for anybody other than yourself.